How to convert the <table> element into Grid
I got the html source code for this  element for this page in Wikipedia:
<table class="wikitable"> 
 <tbody>
  <tr> 
   <th><a href="/wiki/Hermann-Mauguin_notation" class="mw-redirect" title="Hermann-Mauguin notation">Hermann-Mauguin</a> </th> 
   <th><a href="/wiki/Schoenflies_notation" title="Schoenflies notation">Schoenflies</a> </th> 
   <th><a href="/wiki/Order_(group_theory)" title="Order (group theory)">Order</a> </th> 
   <th colspan="2"><a href="/wiki/List_of_small_groups" title="List of small groups">Abstract group</a> </th>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td>1</td> 
   <td><i>C<sub>1</sub></i></td> 
   <td>1</td> 
   <td><a href="/wiki/Trivial_group" title="Trivial group">C<sub>1</sub></a></td> 
   <td><span class="mwe-math-element"><span class="mwe-math-mathml-inline mwe-math-mathml-a11y" style="display: none;">
      <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="{\displaystyle G_{1}^{1}}"> 
       <semantics> 
        <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
         <mstyle displaystyle="true" scriptlevel="0"> 
          <msubsup> 
           <mi>
            G
           </mi> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             1
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             1
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
          </msubsup> 
         </mstyle> 
        </mrow> 
        <annotation encoding="application/x-tex">
         {\displaystyle G_{1}^{1}}
        </annotation> 
       </semantics> 
      </math></span><img src="https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/0d25e00207b473def7c961593ce3cd98dd80a49c" class="mwe-math-fallback-image-inline mw-invert" aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align: -1.005ex; width:2.881ex; height:3.176ex;" alt="{\displaystyle G_{1}^{1}}"></span> </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td><span style="text-decoration:overline;">1</span></td> 
   <td><i>C<sub>i</sub> = S<sub>2</sub></i></td> 
   <td>2</td> 
   <td rowspan="3"><a href="/wiki/Cyclic_group" title="Cyclic group">C<sub>2</sub></a></td> 
   <td rowspan="3"><span class="mwe-math-element"><span class="mwe-math-mathml-inline mwe-math-mathml-a11y" style="display: none;">
      <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="{\displaystyle G_{2}^{1}}"> 
       <semantics> 
        <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
         <mstyle displaystyle="true" scriptlevel="0"> 
          <msubsup> 
           <mi>
            G
           </mi> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             2
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             1
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
          </msubsup> 
         </mstyle> 
        </mrow> 
        <annotation encoding="application/x-tex">
         {\displaystyle G_{2}^{1}}
        </annotation> 
       </semantics> 
      </math></span><img src="https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/1174a2e4bde969cc5660ac37e7cf2d449f34c799" class="mwe-math-fallback-image-inline mw-invert" aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align: -1.005ex; width:2.881ex; height:3.176ex;" alt="{\displaystyle G_{2}^{1}}"></span> </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td>2</td> 
   <td><i>C<sub>2</sub></i></td> 
   <td>2 </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td>m</td> 
   <td><i>C<sub>s</sub> = C<sub>1h</sub></i></td> 
   <td>2 </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td>3</td> 
   <td><i>C<sub>3</sub></i></td> 
   <td>3</td> 
   <td><a href="/wiki/Cyclic_group" title="Cyclic group">C<sub>3</sub></a></td> 
   <td><span class="mwe-math-element"><span class="mwe-math-mathml-inline mwe-math-mathml-a11y" style="display: none;">
      <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="{\displaystyle G_{3}^{1}}"> 
       <semantics> 
        <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
         <mstyle displaystyle="true" scriptlevel="0"> 
          <msubsup> 
           <mi>
            G
           </mi> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             3
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             1
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
          </msubsup> 
         </mstyle> 
        </mrow> 
        <annotation encoding="application/x-tex">
         {\displaystyle G_{3}^{1}}
        </annotation> 
       </semantics> 
      </math></span><img src="https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/db7dc3dc80ca387d2b2f77d680491e28635fda9e" class="mwe-math-fallback-image-inline mw-invert" aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align: -1.005ex; width:2.881ex; height:3.176ex;" alt="{\displaystyle G_{3}^{1}}"></span> </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td>4</td> 
   <td><i>C<sub>4</sub></i></td> 
   <td>4</td> 
   <td rowspan="2"><a href="/wiki/Cyclic_group" title="Cyclic group">C<sub>4</sub></a></td> 
   <td rowspan="2"><span class="mwe-math-element"><span class="mwe-math-mathml-inline mwe-math-mathml-a11y" style="display: none;">
      <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="{\displaystyle G_{4}^{1}}"> 
       <semantics> 
        <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
         <mstyle displaystyle="true" scriptlevel="0"> 
          <msubsup> 
           <mi>
            G
           </mi> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             4
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             1
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
          </msubsup> 
         </mstyle> 
        </mrow> 
        <annotation encoding="application/x-tex">
         {\displaystyle G_{4}^{1}}
        </annotation> 
       </semantics> 
      </math></span><img src="https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/84e4372d852751c4b2b539bac2478e5989bb895f" class="mwe-math-fallback-image-inline mw-invert" aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align: -1.005ex; width:2.881ex; height:3.176ex;" alt="{\displaystyle G_{4}^{1}}"></span> </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td><span style="text-decoration:overline;">4</span></td> 
   <td><i>S<sub>4</sub></i></td> 
   <td>4 </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td>2/m</td> 
   <td>&nbsp;<i>C<sub>2h</sub></i></td> 
   <td>4</td> 
   <td rowspan="3"><a href="/wiki/Klein_four-group" title="Klein four-group">D<sub>2</sub></a> = C<sub>2</sub> * C<sub>2</sub></td> 
   <td rowspan="3"><span class="mwe-math-element"><span class="mwe-math-mathml-inline mwe-math-mathml-a11y" style="display: none;">
      <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="{\displaystyle G_{4}^{2}}"> 
       <semantics> 
        <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
         <mstyle displaystyle="true" scriptlevel="0"> 
          <msubsup> 
           <mi>
            G
           </mi> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             4
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             2
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
          </msubsup> 
         </mstyle> 
        </mrow> 
        <annotation encoding="application/x-tex">
         {\displaystyle G_{4}^{2}}
        </annotation> 
       </semantics> 
      </math></span><img src="https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/64b5a38e50035b536bdab5baaf96bf595aa0ca44" class="mwe-math-fallback-image-inline mw-invert" aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align: -1.005ex; width:2.881ex; height:3.176ex;" alt="{\displaystyle G_{4}^{2}}"></span> </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td>&nbsp;222</td> 
   <td><i>D<sub>2</sub> = V</i></td> 
   <td>4 </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td>mm2</td> 
   <td><i>C<sub>2v</sub></i></td> 
   <td>&nbsp;4 </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td><span style="text-decoration:overline;">3</span></td> 
   <td><i>C<sub>3i</sub> = S<sub>6</sub></i></td> 
   <td>6</td> 
   <td rowspan="3"><a href="/wiki/Cyclic_group" title="Cyclic group">C<sub>6</sub></a></td> 
   <td rowspan="3"><span class="mwe-math-element"><span class="mwe-math-mathml-inline mwe-math-mathml-a11y" style="display: none;">
      <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="{\displaystyle G_{6}^{1}}"> 
       <semantics> 
        <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
         <mstyle displaystyle="true" scriptlevel="0"> 
          <msubsup> 
           <mi>
            G
           </mi> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             6
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             1
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
          </msubsup> 
         </mstyle> 
        </mrow> 
        <annotation encoding="application/x-tex">
         {\displaystyle G_{6}^{1}}
        </annotation> 
       </semantics> 
      </math></span><img src="https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/8e1c517ac3c9f730675e711487dca38f6fd5df30" class="mwe-math-fallback-image-inline mw-invert" aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align: -1.005ex; width:2.881ex; height:3.176ex;" alt="{\displaystyle G_{6}^{1}}"></span> </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td>6</td> 
   <td><i>C<sub>6</sub></i></td> 
   <td>6 </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td><span style="text-decoration:overline;">6</span></td> 
   <td><i>C<sub>3h</sub></i></td> 
   <td>6 </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td>32</td> 
   <td><i>D<sub>3</sub></i></td> 
   <td>6</td> 
   <td rowspan="2"><a href="/wiki/Dihedral_group_of_order_6" title="Dihedral group of order 6">D<sub>3</sub></a></td> 
   <td rowspan="2"><span class="mwe-math-element"><span class="mwe-math-mathml-inline mwe-math-mathml-a11y" style="display: none;">
      <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="{\displaystyle G_{6}^{2}}"> 
       <semantics> 
        <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
         <mstyle displaystyle="true" scriptlevel="0"> 
          <msubsup> 
           <mi>
            G
           </mi> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             6
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             2
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
          </msubsup> 
         </mstyle> 
        </mrow> 
        <annotation encoding="application/x-tex">
         {\displaystyle G_{6}^{2}}
        </annotation> 
       </semantics> 
      </math></span><img src="https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/97b6123d14a431a3408d288a8ab33091bbb88be6" class="mwe-math-fallback-image-inline mw-invert" aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align: -1.005ex; width:2.881ex; height:3.176ex;" alt="{\displaystyle G_{6}^{2}}"></span> </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td>3m</td> 
   <td><i>C<sub>3v</sub></i></td> 
   <td>6 </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td>mmm</td> 
   <td><i>D<sub>2h</sub></i> = <i>V<sub>h</sub></i></td> 
   <td>8</td> 
   <td>D<sub>2</sub> * C<sub>2</sub></td> 
   <td><span class="mwe-math-element"><span class="mwe-math-mathml-inline mwe-math-mathml-a11y" style="display: none;">
      <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="{\displaystyle G_{8}^{3}}"> 
       <semantics> 
        <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
         <mstyle displaystyle="true" scriptlevel="0"> 
          <msubsup> 
           <mi>
            G
           </mi> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             8
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             3
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
          </msubsup> 
         </mstyle> 
        </mrow> 
        <annotation encoding="application/x-tex">
         {\displaystyle G_{8}^{3}}
        </annotation> 
       </semantics> 
      </math></span><img src="https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/308c156140d85eda4c42eab954996bb4a09670aa" class="mwe-math-fallback-image-inline mw-invert" aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align: -1.005ex; width:2.881ex; height:3.176ex;" alt="{\displaystyle G_{8}^{3}}"></span> </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td>&nbsp;4/m</td> 
   <td><i>C<sub>4h</sub></i></td> 
   <td>8</td> 
   <td>C<sub>4</sub> * C<sub>2</sub></td> 
   <td><span class="mwe-math-element"><span class="mwe-math-mathml-inline mwe-math-mathml-a11y" style="display: none;">
      <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="{\displaystyle G_{8}^{2}}"> 
       <semantics> 
        <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
         <mstyle displaystyle="true" scriptlevel="0"> 
          <msubsup> 
           <mi>
            G
           </mi> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             8
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             2
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
          </msubsup> 
         </mstyle> 
        </mrow> 
        <annotation encoding="application/x-tex">
         {\displaystyle G_{8}^{2}}
        </annotation> 
       </semantics> 
      </math></span><img src="https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/5ada708821539b862c5b8ba0ca3cff6fa41dfee6" class="mwe-math-fallback-image-inline mw-invert" aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align: -1.005ex; width:2.881ex; height:3.176ex;" alt="{\displaystyle G_{8}^{2}}"></span> </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td>422</td> 
   <td><i>D<sub>4</sub></i></td> 
   <td>8</td> 
   <td rowspan="3"><a href="/wiki/Dihedral_group_of_order_8" class="mw-redirect" title="Dihedral group of order 8">D<sub>4</sub></a></td> 
   <td rowspan="3"><span class="mwe-math-element"><span class="mwe-math-mathml-inline mwe-math-mathml-a11y" style="display: none;">
      <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="{\displaystyle G_{8}^{4}}"> 
       <semantics> 
        <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
         <mstyle displaystyle="true" scriptlevel="0"> 
          <msubsup> 
           <mi>
            G
           </mi> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             8
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             4
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
          </msubsup> 
         </mstyle> 
        </mrow> 
        <annotation encoding="application/x-tex">
         {\displaystyle G_{8}^{4}}
        </annotation> 
       </semantics> 
      </math></span><img src="https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/b0fc94ae5b040781d41290e6d336c6c184456947" class="mwe-math-fallback-image-inline mw-invert" aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align: -1.005ex; width:2.881ex; height:3.176ex;" alt="{\displaystyle G_{8}^{4}}"></span> </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td>4mm</td> 
   <td><i>C<sub>4v</sub></i></td> 
   <td>8 </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td><span style="text-decoration:overline;">4</span>2m</td> 
   <td><i>D<sub>2d</sub></i> = <i>V<sub>d</sub></i></td> 
   <td>8 </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td>6/m</td> 
   <td><i>C<sub>6h</sub></i></td> 
   <td>12</td> 
   <td>C<sub>6</sub> * C<sub>2</sub></td> 
   <td><span class="mwe-math-element"><span class="mwe-math-mathml-inline mwe-math-mathml-a11y" style="display: none;">
      <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="{\displaystyle G_{12}^{2}}"> 
       <semantics> 
        <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
         <mstyle displaystyle="true" scriptlevel="0"> 
          <msubsup> 
           <mi>
            G
           </mi> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             12
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             2
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
          </msubsup> 
         </mstyle> 
        </mrow> 
        <annotation encoding="application/x-tex">
         {\displaystyle G_{12}^{2}}
        </annotation> 
       </semantics> 
      </math></span><img src="https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/8079425dfa62db8c1807dd37d2e9f0ca33b50832" class="mwe-math-fallback-image-inline mw-invert" aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align: -1.005ex; width:3.703ex; height:3.176ex;" alt="{\displaystyle G_{12}^{2}}"></span> </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td>23</td> 
   <td><i>T</i></td> 
   <td>12</td> 
   <td><a href="/wiki/Alternating_group" title="Alternating group">A<sub>4</sub></a></td> 
   <td><span class="mwe-math-element"><span class="mwe-math-mathml-inline mwe-math-mathml-a11y" style="display: none;">
      <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="{\displaystyle G_{12}^{5}}"> 
       <semantics> 
        <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
         <mstyle displaystyle="true" scriptlevel="0"> 
          <msubsup> 
           <mi>
            G
           </mi> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             12
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             5
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
          </msubsup> 
         </mstyle> 
        </mrow> 
        <annotation encoding="application/x-tex">
         {\displaystyle G_{12}^{5}}
        </annotation> 
       </semantics> 
      </math></span><img src="https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/2f72de8565765aa433e8b9545a2568320c557c1a" class="mwe-math-fallback-image-inline mw-invert" aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align: -1.005ex; width:3.703ex; height:3.176ex;" alt="{\displaystyle G_{12}^{5}}"></span> </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td><span style="text-decoration:overline;">3</span>m</td> 
   <td><i>D<sub>3d</sub></i></td> 
   <td>12</td> 
   <td rowspan="4"><a href="/wiki/Dihedral_group" title="Dihedral group">D<sub>6</sub></a></td> 
   <td rowspan="4"><span class="mwe-math-element"><span class="mwe-math-mathml-inline mwe-math-mathml-a11y" style="display: none;">
      <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="{\displaystyle G_{12}^{3}}"> 
       <semantics> 
        <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
         <mstyle displaystyle="true" scriptlevel="0"> 
          <msubsup> 
           <mi>
            G
           </mi> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             12
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             3
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
          </msubsup> 
         </mstyle> 
        </mrow> 
        <annotation encoding="application/x-tex">
         {\displaystyle G_{12}^{3}}
        </annotation> 
       </semantics> 
      </math></span><img src="https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/f1ca0f72df0a61c70ca8cd7397c627104a690b51" class="mwe-math-fallback-image-inline mw-invert" aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align: -1.005ex; width:3.703ex; height:3.176ex;" alt="{\displaystyle G_{12}^{3}}"></span> </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td>622</td> 
   <td><i>D<sub>6</sub></i></td> 
   <td>12 </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td>6mm</td> 
   <td><i>C<sub>6v</sub></i></td> 
   <td>12 </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td><span style="text-decoration:overline;">6</span>m2</td> 
   <td><i>D<sub>3h</sub></i></td> 
   <td>12 </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td>4/mmm</td> 
   <td><i>D<sub>4h</sub></i></td> 
   <td>16</td> 
   <td>D<sub>4</sub> * C<sub>2</sub></td> 
   <td><span class="mwe-math-element"><span class="mwe-math-mathml-inline mwe-math-mathml-a11y" style="display: none;">
      <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="{\displaystyle G_{16}^{9}}"> 
       <semantics> 
        <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
         <mstyle displaystyle="true" scriptlevel="0"> 
          <msubsup> 
           <mi>
            G
           </mi> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             16
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             9
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
          </msubsup> 
         </mstyle> 
        </mrow> 
        <annotation encoding="application/x-tex">
         {\displaystyle G_{16}^{9}}
        </annotation> 
       </semantics> 
      </math></span><img src="https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/e488c8251fb28ce7cc1cbb2aad22e312dcb7b4af" class="mwe-math-fallback-image-inline mw-invert" aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align: -1.005ex; width:3.703ex; height:3.176ex;" alt="{\displaystyle G_{16}^{9}}"></span> </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td>6/mmm</td> 
   <td><i>D<sub>6h</sub></i></td> 
   <td>24</td> 
   <td>D<sub>6</sub> * C<sub>2</sub></td> 
   <td><span class="mwe-math-element"><span class="mwe-math-mathml-inline mwe-math-mathml-a11y" style="display: none;">
      <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="{\displaystyle G_{24}^{5}}"> 
       <semantics> 
        <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
         <mstyle displaystyle="true" scriptlevel="0"> 
          <msubsup> 
           <mi>
            G
           </mi> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             24
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             5
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
          </msubsup> 
         </mstyle> 
        </mrow> 
        <annotation encoding="application/x-tex">
         {\displaystyle G_{24}^{5}}
        </annotation> 
       </semantics> 
      </math></span><img src="https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/e3f2d88a193181d4507b9e444282e377c8423046" class="mwe-math-fallback-image-inline mw-invert" aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align: -1.005ex; width:3.703ex; height:3.176ex;" alt="{\displaystyle G_{24}^{5}}"></span> </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td>m<span style="text-decoration:overline;">3</span></td> 
   <td><i>T<sub>h</sub></i></td> 
   <td>24</td> 
   <td>A<sub>4</sub> * C<sub>2</sub></td> 
   <td><span class="mwe-math-element"><span class="mwe-math-mathml-inline mwe-math-mathml-a11y" style="display: none;">
      <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="{\displaystyle G_{24}^{10}}"> 
       <semantics> 
        <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
         <mstyle displaystyle="true" scriptlevel="0"> 
          <msubsup> 
           <mi>
            G
           </mi> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             24
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             10
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
          </msubsup> 
         </mstyle> 
        </mrow> 
        <annotation encoding="application/x-tex">
         {\displaystyle G_{24}^{10}}
        </annotation> 
       </semantics> 
      </math></span><img src="https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/b87c5da95e094a54481b431de7a060a671010453" class="mwe-math-fallback-image-inline mw-invert" aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align: -1.005ex; width:3.703ex; height:3.176ex;" alt="{\displaystyle G_{24}^{10}}"></span> </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td>432</td> 
   <td><i>O</i> &nbsp;</td> 
   <td>24</td> 
   <td rowspan="2"><a href="/wiki/Symmetric_group" title="Symmetric group">S<sub>4</sub></a></td> 
   <td rowspan="2"><span class="mwe-math-element"><span class="mwe-math-mathml-inline mwe-math-mathml-a11y" style="display: none;">
      <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="{\displaystyle G_{24}^{7}}"> 
       <semantics> 
        <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
         <mstyle displaystyle="true" scriptlevel="0"> 
          <msubsup> 
           <mi>
            G
           </mi> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             24
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             7
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
          </msubsup> 
         </mstyle> 
        </mrow> 
        <annotation encoding="application/x-tex">
         {\displaystyle G_{24}^{7}}
        </annotation> 
       </semantics> 
      </math></span><img src="https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/deda8b880ce0e1f24bcdfa9186169e117859585d" class="mwe-math-fallback-image-inline mw-invert" aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align: -1.005ex; width:3.703ex; height:3.176ex;" alt="{\displaystyle G_{24}^{7}}"></span> </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td><span style="text-decoration:overline;">4</span>3m</td> 
   <td><i>T<sub>d</sub></i></td> 
   <td>24 </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center"> 
   <td>m<span style="text-decoration:overline;">3</span>m</td> 
   <td><i>O<sub>h</sub></i></td> 
   <td>48</td> 
   <td>S<sub>4</sub> * C<sub>2</sub></td> 
   <td><span class="mwe-math-element"><span class="mwe-math-mathml-inline mwe-math-mathml-a11y" style="display: none;">
      <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="{\displaystyle G_{48}^{7}}"> 
       <semantics> 
        <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
         <mstyle displaystyle="true" scriptlevel="0"> 
          <msubsup> 
           <mi>
            G
           </mi> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             48
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
           <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD"> 
            <mn>
             7
            </mn> 
           </mrow> 
          </msubsup> 
         </mstyle> 
        </mrow> 
        <annotation encoding="application/x-tex">
         {\displaystyle G_{48}^{7}}
        </annotation> 
       </semantics> 
      </math></span><img src="https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/db2001552d2fb44e9c1dc1e71e46328ebf37028c" class="mwe-math-fallback-image-inline mw-invert" aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align: -1.005ex; width:3.703ex; height:3.176ex;" alt="{\displaystyle G_{48}^{7}}"></span> </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

If I use Grid[ImportString[st, {"HTML", "FullData"}][[1, 1, 1]], Frame -> All], I will lose a lot of information in the source code, such as <sub> subscript information, cell cross-line information. Is there a better way to recover this table from this html string?

The <image> element I can think of as an empty string
latex formulas do not need to be rendered, just displayed as is


The brute force approach could be to import as "XMLObject" instead of "FullData" and manually process the table structure

@LukasLang So how do you turn those XMLObject into a Grid?

What do you require as output? It might be possible to obtain the innerHTML of each th and td tags as strings, eg for row2 {"1", "<i>C<sub>1</sub></i>", "1", "<a href=\"/wiki/Trivial_group\" \ title=\"Trivial group\">C<sub>1</sub></a>"} but I think it would  be very difficult to get Mathematica to render HTML?

@user1066 I want to get a Grid as the title

The sentence "The  element I can think of as an empty string" does not make any sense to me.

@yode I actually figured that out. But do you want each cell in the grid to have rendered HTML or 'raw' HTML (such as "C1")?

@user1066 I want to get such grid.  Of course we should render C<sub>1</sub> and keep those cell cross-line information
